# What do you call a $k$-chromatic graph that’s $k+1$-chromatic if you add any arbitrary edge?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an existing term for this? I imagine it’d be something like “maximally k-chromatic”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete $k$-partite graph.

Answer (score 2):

If there is such a term, I would imagine "maximally $k$-chromatic" would be it. However, it would be best to explicitly define "maximally $k$-chromatic" as you did here, so there is no confusion.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think I should use the term “complete k partite graph”, as that’s well established, but I may still take your advice and explicitly define a “maximally k chromatic” term based on coloring properties and describe how it’s identical to a complete k partite graph, since a complete k partite graph isn’t specifically about coloring.